# Left Join no trabaja como espero

Tags: sql, join

Estoy haciendo una consulta en MSSQL en donde debo unir varias tablas a través de Joins. Mi tabla principal consta de Propietarios y Productos (ambas columnas son Key). Tengo otra tabla temporal que consta de Productos, Cantidades, Categorías y Propietarios de Categorías a la cual estoy haciendo un left join a la principal usando las columnas Key de ambas. Tengo dos tablas adicionales las cuales poseen Inventarios Iniciales, Inventarios Finales, Productos y Propietarios a las que también estoy haciendo LEFT JOIN a la principal. El tema es que en ciertas situaciones el query no funciona cuando no existe información en la tabla temporal y anula los datos de la tabla de inventarios.
Este es el resultado esperado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el resultado obtenido:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando tengo movimientos asociados al producto que estoy consultando funciona bien:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi query es el siguiente:

```
SELECT -- MAIN REPORT               
cow.OW_ID AS Propietario_INV,               
cow.C_ID AS Producto,               
ISNULL(inv_ini.INV, 0) AS INV_INI,              
ISNULL(inv_fin.INV, 0) AS INV_FIN,              
mmt.TIPO as Tipo,               
mmt.O_CAT_TYPE as Categoría,                
mmt.OCS_DESC as Descripcion,                
mmt.QUANTITY as Cantidad,               
mmt.OW_ID as Propietario_MOV                
FROM COMP_OWNER cow             
            
LEFT JOIN #TABLA_TEMP mmt               
ON cow.C_ID = mmt.C_ID  AND cow.OW_ID =  mmt.OW_ID              
            
LEFT JOIN --ADD INITIAL INVENTORIES                 
(SELECT                 
    C_ID,       
    OW_ID,      
    COH_NSV AS INV      
    FROM COMP_OWNER_HIST coh        
    WHERE OM_ID = 'MIDNIGHT' and COH_TIMESTAMP= @INICIO         
    GROUP BY OW_ID, C_ID, COH_NSV) inv_ini      
ON inv_ini.C_ID = cow.C_ID  and inv_ini.OW_ID = cow.OW_ID               
            
LEFT JOIN --ADD FINAL INVENTORIES               
(SELECT                 
    C_ID,       
    OW_ID,      
    COH_NSV AS INV      
    FROM COMP_OWNER_HIST coh        
    where COH_TIMESTAMP = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @FIN)         
    GROUP BY OW_ID, C_ID, COH_NSV) inv_fin      
ON inv_fin.C_ID = cow.C_ID and inv_fin.OW_ID = cow.OW_ID
```

Comment: Estoy validando tu consulta y no veo nada mal, debería funcionar, no se si agregas algún where en tu consulta.

Comment: ¿El resultado obtenido no te devuelve `NULL` en ninguna columna, pero si te devuelve filas con cadenas vacías? ¡No lo creo!

Comment: Asi es. Me devuelve filas vacías. Al no haber movimientos me anula todo el query. Funciona bien mientras se hayan registrado movimientos en el periodo de tiempo seleccionado. Es frustrante esta consulta. No veo el error.